# OPE coefficents and commutation relations, and OPE with stress tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Basic question about conformal field theory: In a conformal field theory in $d\geq 3$ dimensions, what is the relation between commutation relations and OPE coefficients?

In particular, because generators of conformal transformations are "made of" the stress tensor, e.g. $$D \sim \int d^2x~ T_{0\nu} x^\nu , $$ what can one say about the OPE of an operator $O_i$ (with scaling dimension $\Delta$ and spin $s$) and the stress tensor?

Comment: Are you after a Ward identity like (3.3) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2891.pdf?